# Desktop email client for Ubuntu that syncs folders with Outlook?

Tags: linux, gratis, email-client, microsoft-exchange

I use [Microsoft Office Outlook 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook/) on my Windows computer to sync emails with folders connected to my Outlook (previously known as hotmail) email address. I have yet to find an email client that will do the same job, but on Ubuntu. I have tried [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) (the default email client for Ubuntu) but that doesn't sync the existing folders I have on my outlook email account. I am willing to take plugin recommendations, or workarounds, if needed.

Features I am looking for

- Free
- Syncs existing and new emails with the folders they are in
- Send emails
- Rich text editor for sending emails
- Ability to add attachments
- Notification when a new email has arrived
- Ability to change how often new emails are checked
- Ability to add multiple accounts
- Contacts list (with the ability to add and remove, and import and export)

Option features

- Calender, with the ability to push new changes to the email server (if possible)
- Ability to change the UI (for example the colour scheme, or the position of existing buttons)

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://superuser.com/questions/461702/is-it-possible-to-use-activesync-to-access-my-folders-in-thunderbird-when-using).  It appears like there is a licensing issue that prevents people from developing an ActiveSync plugin.

Comment: Thunderbird does all that for me the only things that it is not doing are marking things all involve updating the outlook end are you setting up for smtp or pop3?

Comment: @SteveBarnes It automatically syncs your outlook folders?

Comment: I think that is what the `copy folders` plug in does.

Comment: That's strange: I use Thunderbird in a similar setting (though with a corporate account with Office 365, do these work differently from ex-Hotmail accounts?). [I'm not satisfied with the calendar integration](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/98) but the basic email capabilities (sending and receiving email, synchronizing email archives, notifications) work. IIRC you do need to explicitly subscribe to the folders you want to sync.

Comment: Could you provide more details about set up you used on TB.  TB should be able to synchronise all folders